# Combatting debug code in release product

Tags: debugging, release, startup

I work in a very small startup development shop (3 developers), and am often pulled away from what I am working on to fix a mission critical bug or implement an "absolutely critical" software feature - my bug list is re-prioritized on an almost daily basis and I seldom know what will be "important" a a few hours from now.

Because of this, I have found that I am becoming more and more wary of adding code that can potentially go unchecked by our QA department (read: person).

When I implement a new function, not knowing whether I'll be called away from it at any time, I sometimes try to write a return statement at the top just to make sure that the code never gets executed on a release build.

The problem with statements like:

```
public void NewFunction()
{
    return; // Put break point so that I can use the debugger to step to meat:

    meat:
    // ... More code
}
```

are that even in debug mode, Visual Studio is smart enough to know that meat: will never be executed, so you can't use the "set next statement" command to meat:. The same is true for wrapping code in compiler directives like #if !DEBUG.

Instead, I write things like:

```
public void NewFunction()
{
    if("a"[0]=='a')
        return; // put break point here

    meat:
    // ... More code
}
```

so that if this code accidentally slips into a release, no harm is done, but because it's not evaluated until run time, I can use the debugger to step to meat: with no problem.

I don't really like leaving things unfinished, but in crunch times we often don't have time to shelve change sets or do things properly. Access to unfinished features like the function outlines above via an API aren't a concern at the moment, so I don't see any immediate harm in leaving them in the software (but down the line, they can lead to several wtf moments during maintenance - as in "wtf is this function that doesn't do anything doing here?" because I won't remember what I was doing 6 months from now).

Considering that I am (sadly) doing stuff like this on a semi-regular basis, is there a standard practice for this issue? As a larger issue, is there some set of practices that help to combat debug code in software releases in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is in C#, you can use [`[Conditional]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) attribute to exclude certain method calls in Release configuration:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void NewFunction (object something)
{
    // do something
}
```

This is equivalent to wrapping method itself and all its calls into `#if DEBUG` / `#endif` clauses.

Any calls to `NewFunction` will be excluded by compiler when `DEBUG` symbol is not defined. The simplest way to control it is by solution and project configurations in Visual Studio. In Debug configuration, `DEBUG` symbol is defined, as opposed to Relase configuraiton.

Note that only `void` calls can be excluded because code doesn't depend on return values for these methods.

However this is designed to be used for tracing, logging etc. I don't quite understand how you plan to leave some methods unfinished yet still use them in debug versions. What's the sense of calling them if they don't work, or if they do, why not include them in release?

Answer (score 2):

A few things stand out to me:

- "I don't really like leaving things unfinished,"
- "I sometimes try to write a return statement at the top just to make sure that the code never gets executed on a release build."
- "so that if this code accidentally slips into a release"

I would look up some Agile methodologies and practices. It was designed to take into account fast moving targets in the release.

You should do the following:

- Ensure all your new code has unit tests backing up their functionality.
- Write unit tests for code you change to ensure that what you changed didn't break existing functionality.
- Perform continuous builds with Cruise Control or a similar product. This along with the tests will let you know immediately when something breaks.
- Start branching by features/tasks so that no code "accidently" slips in. Working off the mainline for all of your code, even when you move from one priority task to another will lead to these slips.
- The product should always work. At any point in time given X number of features that are completed in the product, it should work. Don't half implement a feature. Break it up into smaller features and tasks that you can say work. It doesn't matter if the customer will never use them. This prevents unfinished features that are then used by another developer and break.
- Fix broken windows. Don't let very bad design or bugs continue to exist. It only compound the problem later.

By adhering to the task/feature branching you won't have to create intermediate code that will be checked in like you have in your question. That should not happen. If you switch tasks that will be in another branch. Make it so your process is minimal and your branching is effortless. Then these things will be second nature.

Answer (score 1):

Distributed version control systems make branching and merging a snap. With a tool like Mercurial (my personal preference), you don't even need a remote repository -- you just create the repo in-place on your local system, then clone the repo elsewhere on your local drive. So you can easily keep a "release" version of your code while rapidly migrating code changes to and from a "debug" branch.

Comment: I'm not sure just the fact of using a DVCS will help much. If you're in a situation where you're constantly being interrupted, you really wouldn't want to have to deal with the extra overhead of having to merge changes back and forth. I'd say the OP is on the right track with the IF command structure, but I'd check my DEBUG options. it seems like if all the optimations were turned off in DEBUG mode, the compiler SHOULDN'T be optimizing out that unreachable code. But I haven't tried it explicitly yet.

Comment: I disagree. If you're talking two clean branches that you maintain yourself, merges should take literally seconds.

Comment: +1. Mercurial is great, but personally, I like git even better (it does have a steep learning curve, though), and git offers a variety of ways (in addition to a regular merge) in which you can combine branches - for instance, you can _rebase_, which will keep your history from becoming full of merges. Another advantage of a DVCS (whichever kind) is that you don't need to convince management of its merits; you can have the repository on your own machine, and nobody else will be "bothered" by it.

Comment: The axe I have to grind in the mercurial vs. git ideological battle is much, much smaller than the one I have for the DVCS vs. centralized VCS battle. I use Hg because it suits me, and I acknowledge that git would probably serve equally as well. That said, I would argue that the ability for a single developer to run a "stealth repo" on his local box is actually one of the few *downsides* to DVCS. If you are working on a team and you're not sharing code via revision control, You're Doing It Wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation.  I sometimes put #IF DEBUG around the call to new function. Or #IF DEBUG around the entire contents of a function.

The other thing I do is put TODO:Unit Test comment on the function so that at release time I can search for those and know if there is a problem.